# compressing json response from asp.net server in a shared hosting environment

Tags: asp.net, json, iis, web-config, gzip

My hosting server is godaddy on a shared hosting environment.
Because of shared hosting environment I do not have access to IIS settings.

For many purposes I send json response to ajax request

I have set the following in my web.config file

```
<httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
            <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll"/>
            <dynamicTypes>
                <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
                <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
                <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true"/>
                <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
            </dynamicTypes>
            <staticTypes>
                <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
                <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
                <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true"/>
                <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
            </staticTypes>
        </httpCompression>
```

I can make my .aspx pages gziped but It is not compressing json responses.
How can I compress json responses..??

Comment: really..? It's more than 1 year and no response.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is that you need your own VPS server (if you are on a budget) or your own dedicated server. Then you can modify the applicationHost.config for IIS7